# It will be finished/built soon

Tags: future-constructions, future

I found these sentences in a grammar book:

> They're building a new hospital. It will **be finished** soon.

I'm wondering, since the simple tense means completion, can we say

> They're building a new hispital. It will **be built** soon.

instead?

Comment: what simple tense are you talking about?  There is a future passive "will be built"

Comment: @JamesK Yes, the future simple passive. As I know we can say "It will be built" only about objects that will be finished. That's why I've asked this question.

Answer (score 1):

"be built" is quite vague, it can mean it has not started building or is close to finishing the building. Meanwhile "be finished" means it is close to being finished. So I would rather stick with "be finished" here.

Comment: Thanks! Is it grammatically wrong to use the option with "be built"? As I know we can say "It will be built" only about objects that will be finished. E.g. It **was built** two years ago. = It **was finished** two years ago.

Comment: No it is not grammatically wrong to use it, it just a little vague, so you can use it @IlyaTretyakov

Comment: _It was built two years ago_ doesn't necessarily mean that the construction was _finished_ exactly two years ago; the work could have been going on for part of the year before last.

Comment: @KateBunting thanks. Never before have I been so confused/surprised in my life, because many people say that the past simple is only about finished actions/objects. Could you, Kate, please tell me, how is that possible?

Comment: I didn't mean to imply that _it was built_ doesn't mean that the project is finished!  I meant that _being built_ can refer to the period while construction is ongoing. So your 'It will be built soon' could mean 'The work will start soon', and you need to say _finished_ or _completed_ to specify that the work is over (or call the hospital _newly built_).

Comment: @KateBunting sorry, **my brain just refuses to understand** it. If "it was/will be built" means that the project was/will be completed, how can it possibly refer to the period while construction is ongoing? Example: Somebody just started a new project. Now it is being built, but it **isn't** built yet, because it is **only being built,** so it will be built/finished in the future.

Comment: "It was/will be built" means that the construction took place/will take place. When speaking of an older building, "It was built in 1960" probably means that it was completed in that year. However, for a recent or current project, 'being built' may well refer to the ongoing work rather than the completion.

Comment: @KateBunting 
_>>However, for a recent or current project, 'being built' may well refer to the ongoing work rather than the completion._
So, after all that I've heard from so many natives(different opinions) is this correct to say, "What did you do yesterday evening?" "I **built a wooden ship"** (I'm planning to finish it next week)

Comment: Oh, dear - this is very hard to explain! In this case, you would probably say _I did some work on the model ship that I'm building_.